# I am Facing issue in TinyMCE Content Loading

Tags: javascript, tinymce

```
   Some times TinyMCE Edit Content is Displaying all the Content in **HTML tags**?
```

Is there any one have Solution for this issue?I am using Asp.net & **TinyMCE Version 3**

Comment: Hey mate, where is your code?

Comment: try change `<html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you display only textbox with html code inside.